# Can't post to firebase's database

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I try to post data with postman to firebase I get this error:
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field body).

I checked and body and userHandle comes back as undefined but I don't know why. With postman I use POST and in the body I send a json like this:

```
{
    "body": "scream 2",
    "userHandle": "user2"
}
```

as raw JSON(application/json)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

let firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '*******',
  authDomain: '******',
  databaseURL: '*****',
  projectId: '*****',
  storageBucket: '****',
  messagingSenderId: '*****',
  appId: '*******'
};

admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


exports.createScream = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Method not allowed' });
  }
  const newScream = {
    body: req.body.body,
    userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
    createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
  };

  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('screams')
    .add(newScream)
    .then(doc => {
      res.json({ message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully` });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong' });
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Vilmos and welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not spotting anything that you're obviously doing wrong... can you include a `console.log(req.body)` as the first line of your function, and then [check your function logs](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/functions/logs) to see what's coming through as the whole body?

Comment: { "body":"scream", "userHandle":"user2" }  
And I tried with express + body-parser but I got the same error.

Comment: Idea time... though I doubt this will fix it - but I recommend you follow [best practices to ensure your cloud function has enough time to run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) by returning your promise... meaning `return admin.firestore().colle....etc...` Never know, maybe the cloud function is terminating before it finishes "adding" the new entry... and so when it *does* finally "add" the new entry, the request/response cycle has already ended... and req.body is now empty.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay it's a little weird but in postman the body was set to raw JSON (application/json)but I set it again to JSON(application/json) and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to my experience:

Lot of people while using postman forget to change the body to JSON (by Default it's text). Check the picture below:[image]

So if you will see in the right-end you will find JSON highlighted in orange color. That must be set to JSON (If you are trying to push JSON ofcourse). By default i found that it is in text.

Rest about the code you have posted in the question is up to mark.

I really thought it might help someone facing the simliar problem therefore decided to mention this.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that one of the fields you're adding to the Firestore document is undefined:

```
  const newScream = {
    body: req.body.body,
    userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
    createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
  };
```

Since what you're showing is all variables whose values we can't see, we can't tell which one might be undefined.  You will have to debug this on your own to figure out which one is undefined, and modify your code to check that the inputs are valid.

Comment: I already said that body and userHandle comes back as undefined but I don't know why. The inputs should be valid.

Comment: When I use hard coded data in the .add() function it's works but with postman it doesn't.